# PowerShell: How can I determine if Invoke-WebRequest has timed out?

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I need to produce some output when Invoke-WebRequest exceeds the time limit set by the -TimeoutSec parameter. How can I build an If condition that runs when this is the case?

In other words; what goes in place of ????? in the example below?:

```
Try {
  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -contentType "application/json"
   -Method Post -Headers $Headers -Body $Body -TimeoutSec 8
}
Catch {
 If (?????) {
    Write-Host "the request timed out..."
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?

Comment: I'm using version 5 on this specific device but can upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows PowerShell, the exception thrown will be a `[System.Net.WebException]` with the `Status` field set to `Timeout`:

```
try{
  Invoke-WebRequest 'http://hostname.fqdn/really/slow/endpoint/' -TimeoutSec 3 -UseBasicParsing
}
catch [System.Net.WebException] {
  if($_.Exception.Status -eq 'Timeout'){
    # the request timed out
  }
  # something else went wrong during the web request
}
```